# Headless rendering on remote Ubuntu server results in blank render

Tags: rendering, command-line

If I try and render [this .blend](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqKxXPZzafVQlrQYhQ72eO6bSd-HRA) on my Windows machine, using this command, I get the correct output:

```
.\blender.exe -b testrender.blend -f 0 -F PNG -o frame_0.png
```

The correct render:

[image]

If I try to do the same on my remote Ubuntu 16.04 server, with this command, I just get a blank, grey .png file outputted:

```
blender -b testrender.blend -f 0 -F PNG -o frame_0.png
```

The incorrect render:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Both the 'correct' and 'incorrect' images are the same image.

Comment: @RayMairlot Thanks. This has now been corrected.